# jQuery clear cache on logout

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, jquery-mobile

When users logout from my mobile app, how can I make sure the cache is cleared?

What I'm thinking about is to redirect /logout to a specific page that clears the cache and redirects to the front page, but how do I clear everything from the cache?

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.0b2pre.

Comment: Update: Server side `Cache-Control` etc wont work. We need JavaScript to do this.

Comment: because jQuery loads every page into the DOM and after that doesn't even query the server, unless you tell it to do so manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I solved it:

My `/logout` action where the users session is destroyed in the backend redirects to `/exit` which has an id attribute of `exitPage`.
In my JavaScript I have asked jQuery Mobile to trigger when that page is about to be created. I then empty the DOM and redirects to the front page.

/exit:

```
<div data-role="page" id="exitPage"></div>
```

/my.js:

```
jQuery('#exitPage').live('pagebeforecreate', function(){
    jQuery(document).empty();
    window.location.replace('/');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't clear the cache. but what you can do is identify the user based on his session id, and append that to the assets urls `someimage.png?cachecontrol=blablalba` next time it enters, he will have a new session id so he will get new files even if the old ones are still in the cache. the other solution will be to explicitly set the cache control header to no-cache. but you can't force his browser to clear it's cache

Comment: I'm not worried about the caching of images etc, only page content. Like a users settings page etc.

Comment: you can add the cache thing to everything not just images. that was just an example. for sensitive pages you can tell the browser via headers that it should not cache it at all.

Comment: I would like to have everything cached. But when the user logs out, the pages content cache should be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid changing the URL of all your pages, you could send an `ETag` header with each response in the session based on the session ID. If you also include `Cache-Control:must-revalidate`, this should do the trick.

Comment: Server side wont work as dynamic pages already use `Cache-Control`. jQuery Mobile caches content, and I need a way to remove anything from jQuery Mobile's cache.