# clear dom cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi in my mobile application I have multiple pages in different files. I want to clear Dom cache at certain level and call login page I am doing like this:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.empty();
$.mobile.loadPage('login.html');
```

But it is not working, it only shows white screen, I also add above inside try block still same issue. How I can clear cache?  Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691998/jquery-clear-cache-on-logout

Answer (score 0):

`$.mobile.loadPage` command pre-fetches the page but doesn't show it. [The documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html) says

> This function does not affect the current active page so it can be used to load pages in the background.

You probably want to call `$.mobile.changePage('login.html')`. You can also drop the loadPage since changePage calls it if the page is not in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but $.mobile.changePage('login.html') also not works